# Display marker over dicom image from CADSR file that are necessary to show

Tags: dicom

I am trying to read an CADSR file I get an various marker from "Graphics Data Tag" I want to show only those marker over the Dicom file that are necessary so let me know what criteria is required to showing up the necessary marker over dicom image

This is the actual output that shown in below image

[image: Actual Image]

but I get such kind of Image opuput which is wrong

[image: wrong result O/P]

In the wrong O/P Image there are multiple markers at specific location I want to combine that marker and show single marker as Star for this.Also one marker is not required that display the out of scope of image that marker I don't want to display so how it can be handle from dicom tags or any things required to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing everything that has a graphic data type. So you are showing the centre of the breast and the nipple.

The cluster of marks is a calcification cluster. A calcification cluster contains multiple calcifications each with their own graphic data type.

Look at the documentation for the R2 Server. You are interested in three objects Malcs, Calcs and Mass. A Malc contains a Mass and a calcifiation cluster which you will need to take account of.